# Tips on making this for loop a vector function instead, if possible

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is use vectorization operations to speed up my code, if it is possible to do so here.  For instance, slicing an array may be faster.  Here is my snippet of code:

```
def rotated_point(x,y,z):
    """
    Inputs:
        x,y,z:(old) original coordinates of atom
    Returns:
        x,y,z:(new) new coordinates of atom after rotation 
               about lower-left H-C bond
    """
    x_new = (((c4x*(v**2+w**2)-u*(c4y*v+c4z*w-u*x-v*y-w*z))*(1-cos(d))+
        L*x*cos(d)+sqrt(L)*(-c4z*v+c4y*w-w*y+v*z)*sin(d))/L)

    y_new = (((c4y*(u**2+w**2)-v*(c4x*u+c4z*w-u*x-v*y-w*z))*(1-cos(d))+
        L*y*cos(d)+sqrt(L)*(c4z*u-c4x*w+w*x-u*z)*sin(d))/L)

    z_new = (((c4z*(u**2+v**2)-w*(c4x*u+c4y*v-u*x-v*y-w*z))*(1-cos(d))+
        L*z*cos(d)+sqrt(L)*(-c4y*u+c4x*v-v*x+u*y)*sin(d))/L)
   return x_new, y_new, z_new

x = [c1x, c2x, c3x, c4x, c5x, c6x, h1x, h2x, h3x, h4x, h5x, h6x]
y = [c1y, c2y, c3y, c4y, c5y, c6y, h1y, h2y, h3y, h4y, h5y, h6y]
z = [c1z, c2z, c3z, c4z, c5z, c6z, h1z, h2z, h3z, h4z, h5z, h6z]
x_r = []
y_r = []
z_r = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    if (i==1 or i==3 or i==7 or i==9):
        x_r.append(x[i])
        y_r.append(y[i])
        z_r.append(z[i])
    else:
        x_new, y_new, z_new = rotated_point(x[i], y[i], z[i])
        x_r.append(x_new)
        y_r.append(y_new)
        z_r.append(z_new)
```

Is there a way to make this a vector function.

Comment: What do you mean by "vector function?" Could you describe what your function is doing, and what you would like it to do instead?

Comment: I would like to use vectorization operations; mainly, i would like to speed up my code by ridding of for loops wherever i can. This code basically performs the rotated _points() function if the indices are not the ones specified

Comment: Do you mean using `numpy` ufuncs?

Comment: @PaulRooney I am aware. My question is more does the OP want to use built-in `numpy` `ufuncs` or does OP want to write a [numpy extension](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html) to make whatever calculation a `ufunc` leveraging compiled C code?

Comment: just using ufuncs.  I do not wish to write a numpy extension at this point

Comment: @JordanPagni can you edit your post to include the `rotated_point` function

Comment: the rotated points func just takes input cartesion points and outputs the new points after being rotated around a line.